# changing user selection color

Tags: html, css

I hate it when I'm browsing and end up selecting text or elements on a webpage by accident; everything turns blue! So for the moment, I'm using this class on the parts of the page where the user could mistakenly select things:

```
.NoSelect{
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;}
```

This works fine but the problem is that I end up with lots of divs that have this class.

Is there a way to change the color of selected text and selected elements and make it transparent?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you apply this class to your `<body>`?

Comment: @ZoltanToth: because there are areas where the user can select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aselection) CSS attribute.

for everything:

```
::selection { background: transparent; }
```

or just `p` tags, for example:

```
p::selection { background: transparent; }
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/a7t3x/).